# From plist to UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, plist, uipicker

I have a plist that I want to get the contents of in a uipickerview.

I'm able to output the contents of the plist in the console using:

```
    // Path to the plist (in the application bundle)
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                                        @"loa" ofType:@"plist"];

    // Build the array from the plist  
    NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    // Show the string values  
    for (NSString *str in array2)
            NSLog(@"--%@", str);
```

what I need to figure out is how to get this content into the UIPickerView.

I tried the following:

```
        arrayPicker = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:array2];
```

, but get an error: `exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDataDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSLog(@"MyDict:%@",[myDataDictionary description]);
```

Your plist file is an NSDictionary;

Answer (score 1):

You've got to use the picker delegate/datasource

First, make the array a property loaded in the viewDidLoad, i.e.:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                                        @"loa" ofType:@"plist"];
self.myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
```

THEN

Conform your class to picker delegate/datasource, and hook it up in IB.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [myArray count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [myArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

What is the structure of your plist? - Is it just a flat array, or an array assigned to a one-key dict, or a dict with key/object pairs...

Comment: the plist is an Array with a Dictionary and 4 strings within the dictionary for each item. I tried something similar to what you have above but kept getting the error "myArray" undeclared.